# ¿ como crear un tooltip generico con jquery que para usarlo solo le pase los parametros?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Quiero crear un tooltip generico que solo se pueda usar pasansole parametros como es el texto y el estilo.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, sería recomendable que la reescribas para tener respuestas, de todos modos, si necesitas un tooltip básico, te recomendaría que uses un plugin como el de [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default) no se si amerita reinventar la rueda

Comment: aquí un link de como hacer un tooltip aunque es sin jquery es solo con html y css --> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

Comment: Bootstrap tiene uno muy bueno https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como han dicho bien en los comentarios hay muchas formas de hacer un tooltip. La mejor manera (si no quieres utilizar mucho codigo/boostrap) es con Jquery.

#### Planteamiento

1. Se utilizaría la función [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), que permite coger el valor de un atributo sin que este sea valido para html.
2. A continuación crearías un elemento con la función [.prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) que permite añadir texto dentro del elemento.
3. Luego de eso haces un evento de hover y luego utilizas la función de [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) que pemite buscar dentro un elemento.
4. Y le añadiriamos una clase con la función [.css()](http://api.jquery.com./css/) que permite modificar el css

Y bueno, luego de plantear como sería el codigo básicamente solo hace falta añadir el css y html

#### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tooltip").css("visibility","hidden");
  var mensaje = $(".tooltip-element").attr("tooltip-info");
  $(".tooltip-element").prepend(''+mensaje+'');
  $(".tooltip-element").hover(function(){
     $(this).find(".tooltip").css("visibility","visible");
  },function(){
     $(this).find(".tooltip").css("visibility","hidden");
  });
});
```

#### CSS

El CSS permite posicionar al elemento donde toca

```
.tooltip-element{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.tooltip-element .tooltip{
    visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: -60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

#### HTML

Un texto de ejemplo con 2 tooltips

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
```

#### Prueba

https://jsfiddle.net/matahombres/9edLpxq8/

Comment: Hola Matahombres! Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Pero ten en cuenta que no todas las preguntas deben responderse. Han de tener una calidad minima y en este caso le falta añadir explicacion suficiente de lo que quiere y sobre todo de lo que ha intentado para que podamos ayudarle sobre sus errores, no sobre sus tareas. Un saludo